# Обработка файла

Tags: php

Добрый день. Есть файл txt. В нём на каждой строке есть надпись c цифрами через пробел, нужно перебрать этот файл и убрать пробелы между цифрами и заменить их на двоеточие, Было 455155     15151, Хочу сделать 455155:15151 Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь вы попытаетесь разобраться как это работает, что бы не задавать потом подобных вопросов.

```
$list=file("file_name.txt");
$fo=fopen("file_name.txt",'w+');
foreach($list as $line) {
    fwrite($fo,str_replace(' ',':',$line));
}
fclose($fo);
```

Comment: Не работает

Comment: работает, не хватало закрывающей скобки

Comment: пометьте пожалуйста что это для небольших файлов, для больших надо делать потоком с временным файлом.

Comment: это уже совсем другая история, не по сабжу